# javascript splice() causes "arrayName.splice() is not a function" error

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to remove certain values from an array containing input fields in a form:

```
allFields = theForm.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");

for(j = 0; j < allFields.length; j++) {
    if(allFields[j].className == "btn" || allFields[j].className == "lnk") {
        allFields.splice(j,1);
    }
}
```

It causes an error. Firebug shows following error and the script doesn't work.

> allFields.splice is not a function

This also happened with any other Array method I tried. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

allFields is not an array, but a `NodeList`.

If you want to remove elements, do a reverse loop and use removeChild:

```
var allFields = theForm.getElementsByTagName("input");
for(var j=allFields.length-1; j>=0; j--){
    if(allFields[j].className == "btn" || allFields[j].className == "lnk"){
        allFields[j].parentNode.removeChild(allFields[j]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Firefox says it's a HTMLCollection, but according to the book "JavaScript: The Definitive Guide", by David Flanagan, it's a NodeList (page 767).

Comment: [`getElementsByTagName`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#method-getElementsByTagName) returns a [`NodeList`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-DOM-Level-1/level-one-core.html#ID-536297177).

Comment: Well, that's a [bug in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=14869) then. `document.getElementsByTagName('a') instanceof NodeList` evaluates to `true` in Chrome, but Firefox says `false`. *edit: yes it's a bug*

Comment: It's not a bug as per the DOM standard. `HTMLCollection` correctly implements the `NodeList` interface. DOM doesn't say anything about concrete classes or `instanceof` having to match anything, it only requires that the described methods be present on the return objects. You can't even be sure that a `NodeList` constructor function will be present as a `window` property or that testing against it is meaningful.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that.
Why does it have to be a reverse loop?
Is it possible to remove child with allFields.removeChild(allFields[j]) ??

Comment: If you remove a node, the loop will skip the next node. That's because the NodeList is dynamic. This story applies to arrays too.