# splice method not working

Tags: javascript, html

I am getting all the input values of text boxes. Then store all the input values to an array. If the input type is button it should be removed from the array. This is my code.

```
<!-- language : java script -->    
function nullchecaking(){

    var arr = new Array();
    arr = document.getElementsByTagName('input');
    var a
    for(a=0; a<arr.length;a++){

        if(arr[a].type == "button"){
            alert("found button");
            arr.splice(a, 1);
            alert(arr);
            a=a-1;  
        }
    }

}
```

splice method not working. How can i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that `getElementsByTagName` returns an array-like object, not an array, so you can't call array methods on it.  But there's a simple workaround:

```
arr.splice(a, 1);
```

would become

```
Array.prototype.splice.call(arr, a, 1);
```

---

EDIT

Sorry - it seems as though the proper way to remove items from what's returned by `getElementsByTagName`—which is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)—is to use `removeChild` as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3574786/352552)

Comment: yup.. its working. but loop not end. My checking is correct , isn't it?

Comment: yes. Alert always "found button". but i have only one button.

Comment: Maybe this statement is the problem: a=a-1;, when finds button, the index will back to previous value.